# Position Banners

Tags: html, css

I have 3 banners and I want to make like: , without using absolute position (I want to use relative position because when I put the footer, the footer is interlaced with page). How can I make it?

```css
.bms {
  height: 810px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(50.5% - 10px);
}

.bds {
  height: 400px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 49.5%;
}

.bdj {
  height: 400px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 417px;
  width: 49.5%;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
  <img class="bms" src="https://.com//image//.png" alt="BMS">
  <img class="bds" src="https://.com////.png" alt="BDS">
  <img class="bdj" src="https://.com////jospng" alt="BDJ">
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: add a container to your images and put a position relative to him.

Comment: Use `bootstrap Grid ` for that

Comment: @BhargavChudasama I want to use classic css code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can consider using a grid.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 0px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  width: 100%;
}

.bms {
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
}

.bds {
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
}

.bdj {
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img class="bms" src="https://.com////.png" alt="BMS">
  <img class="bds" src="https://.com////.png" alt="BDS">
  <img class="bdj" src="https://.com////.png" alt="BDJ">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved with putting float left and right. Thanks for answers!

Answer (score 0):

Using `flex`, you can simply achieve that. So no need to use `float`. Here's the example.

```css
.container{
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height: 600px;
}
.left-banner{
    display: flex;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
}
.left-banner img{
    width: 100%;
}
.right-banner{
    display: flex;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.right-up-banner{
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
}
.right-up-banner img{
    width: 100%;
}
.right-down-banner{
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
}
.right-down-banner img{
    width: 100%;
}
.footer{
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #222;
    height: 200px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left-banner">
    <img src="https://.com////.png" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="right-banner">
    <div class="right-up-banner">
      <img src="https://.com////.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="right-down-banner">
      <img src="https://.com////.png" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
  <h1>Footer</h1>
 </div>
```